# Exclusive Read/Update in Sqlite for a Django web application

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have a simple Django web-app with a Sqlite DB intended for collecting movie reviews from users where every movie is supposed to get exactly 2 reviewers to look at it and provide a review for it.

To implement the 2 reviews/movie requirement dynamically, I have to make sure that I do not present a given movie to more than 2 logged-in users. Otherwise, I will be getting more than 2 reviews for that movie.

Therefore, I need to check before sending any movie for review that it hasn't been sent out to 2 reviewers just yet. Problem is: if I keep this information in the database, I could have more than 2 concurrent requests pick a certain movie and send it out for review because they've all performed the read/retrieve operation concurrently.

Wish I had something like "SELECT FOR UPDATE" but that's not supported in SQLite unfortunately.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [transactions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) to solve your problem. Here's the [appropriate django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/), and [here](http://tomicloud.com/2012/02/django-sqlite) is an example.

It looks like you'll get "OperationalError: database is locked" thrown if you try to let two concurrent transactions write to the same sqlite DB. You would probably want to use the Django ORM (see the links), but here's a hacky example to demonstrate the idea.

```
import sqlite3
# 2 connections, 2 cursors
con = sqlite3.connect('test.db', isolation_level=None)
con2 = sqlite3.connect('test.db', isolation_level=None)
cur = con.cursor()
cur2 = con2.cursor()

# create really simple table
try:
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE MOVIES(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, r1 INTEGER, r2 INTEGER)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO MOVIES(id,r1, r2) VALUES (1,0,0)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO MOVIES(id,r1, r2) VALUES (2,0,0)")
except:
    pass

# awkward read/write split mid-transaction is purely for demonstration purposes..
def read(cursor):
    cursor.execute("BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSACTION")  # get write lock straight away
    data = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM MOVIES WHERE r1 == 0 OR r2 == 0")
    return data.fetchall()

def write(cursor, movie_id, reviewer_column, new_reviewer_id):
    cursor.execute("UPDATE MOVIES SET %s=%d WHERE id == %d AND %s ==0" % (
        reviewer_column, new_reviewer_id, movie_id, reviewer_column))
    cursor.execute("COMMIT")

# works fine
data1 = read(cur) # [(1, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0)]
write(cur, data1[0][0], "r1", 123)

# now we have concurrent access..
data1 = read(cur) # [(1, 123, 0), (2, 0, 0)]
data2 = read(cur2) # throws OperationalError: database is locked.
# the second thread should probably wait a bit before retrying.

# in the mean time..
write(cur, data1[0][0], "r2", 456) #works

# now it's safe for the second thread to retry
data2 = read(cur2) # [(2, 0, 0)]
write(cur2, data2[0][0], "r1", 457) #works
```

Data after the above:

```
# MOVIES
# id |  r1 |  r2
#  1 | 123 | 456
#  2 | 457 |   0
```

It will shield you from putting nonsense in your DB, but the immediate write lock is a slightly crude way of getting there.